# Options for reusing an existing VS project as a base or starter for a new project or using a template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, project-template

I write a lot of example projects (mostly C++ & some C#) for students. A lot of the time the example projects are largely similar, except with the addition of the key feature or technique I happen to be teaching. I like to keep the projects as simple as possible (e.g. 1 feature per project).

Most the projects have a similar starting point, (boilerplate code) and I copy that 'starter project' point into a new folder and start work on that copy as my new project. Next I need to go and change the solution/project/filenames to represent what the sample code demonstrates.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Is there a quick way of generating a template? ASFAIK the template export wizard in VS2010 doesn't work with c++ projects.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to `File`-->`Export template` and let the wizard guide you.

If you need some additional tweaks, you will be able to unzip the template, fix it, and zip it again.

Comment: "Export template" is greyed out for me in VS2012 with a C++ project. From what I can see after a quick google search, the template wizard doesn't export C++ projects

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that as I don't work with C++. You may take one of the out of the box project template, duplicate it and tweak its content to feet your needs (it's an idea, I don't know if it's feasible. One of the other option is maybe to export not the project, but one item. But it's still possible that it's not possible with C++ items (as code is split between .h and .cpp files)